Issues with Running Django Management Command as an Always On Task on PythonAnywhere
I built and deployed my Django website on PythonAnywhere.
I have a script in my
app/management/commands/my_command.py

that I intend to keep always running. I tried using the PythonAnywhere Always On Task feature for this, but the status never changes from "starting" to "running".
There is no problem with the script itself because when I run:
bash
(venv) $ source /home/myusername/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/activate && cd /home/myusername/myproject && python manage.py my_command

the script runs successfully, and then when I go to my Always On Task console, I see that it ran successfully and was recorded in that console.
But the problem is that I don't want to always manually run it in my Bash console.
I have followed the instructions on the PythonAnywhere help page, and I have changed my task command to all the options I can use. I tried:
bash
source virtualenvwrapper.sh && workon myenv && python /home/myusername/myproject/manage.py my_command

But it never changes to "running."
I also tried:
bash
/home/myusername/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/python /home/myusername/myproject/manage.py my_command

Again, it never changes to "running."
However, if I run the script in the Bash console, the Always On task prints out my success message!
What am I doing wrong?

I resolved the issue by specifying the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in the command. The correct command for the Always On Task is:
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings /home/myusername/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/python /home/myusername/myproject/manage.py my_command

This allowed the task to start successfully and run continuously as intended.

As noted from the help page; if the always on process never exists the starting phase, it is due to a failed process and the cause is provided in the task log as noted in the documentation from the link in the link below. review the task log for what is failing and fix that issue.

If the task gets stuck in a "Starting" state, it is likely that it's
crashing as soon as it starts up. The easiest way to work out why is
to look at the task log -- you can access that from the first button
in the "Action" column.

Always on tasks
also worth noting that this functionality is only available for paid accounts. I assume this isn't the case, but worth noting.
